# databinding differences text or apply

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm reading the android docs https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/?hl=en about databing and I found this:

Kotlin

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sample_text).apply {
    text = viewModel.userName
}
```

Java

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
textView.setText(viewModel.getUserName());
```

I wonder why in kotlin is used `apply` instead of `text(aka setText)` function?

Answer (score 2):

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sample_text).apply {
    text = viewModel.userName
}
```

The above code is equivalent to

```
val textView  = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sample_text)
textView.text = viewModel.userName
```

The apply function is a scope function. Its main use case is the [initialization of objects](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6094) and [Builder-style usage of methods that return Unit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#builder-style-usage-of-methods-that-return-unit)

```
fun arrayOfMinusOnes(size: Int): IntArray {
    return IntArray(size).apply { fill(-1) }
}
```

Comment: did this answer your question?